# XPS 13 9300 - fingerprint reader - any driver updates?

Tags: drivers, dell, xps, fingerprint-reader

I have a fingerprint reader and it shows as a Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint.

However, when I check at this site:

[Hardware Probe](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:27c6-533c)

[Linux Hardware Probe](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:27c6-533c)

I find the it fails on this machine with 20.04.

The investigation I have made is as follows:

```
makem@XPS-13-9300:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:    focal
makem@XPS-13-9300:~$
makem@XPS-13-9300:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:58fe Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:533c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
makem@XPS-13-9300:~$

makem@XPS-13-9300:~$ sudo apt-get install fprintd libfprint-2-2 libfprint-2-tod1 libpam-fprintd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
fprintd is already the newest version (1.90.1-1ubuntu1).
libfprint-2-2 is already the newest version (1:1.90.1+tod1-0ubuntu4).
libfprint-2-2 set to manually installed.
libfprint-2-tod1 is already the newest version (1:1.90.1+tod1-0ubuntu4).
libfprint-2-tod1 set to manually installed.
libpam-fprintd is already the newest version (1.90.1-1ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
makem@XPS-13-9300:~$
```

Is there somewhere where new drivers can be found as they are released?

Comment: Since I can't leave comment on above accepted answer. The drivers listed in acceptable answer: ```
http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/pool/public/libf/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/
```
Has been marked as containing trojan, on both VirtusTotal and intezer file analysis. Intezer identifies the drivers as code similar to RealVNC.

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding another answer as it is sufficiently different from my previous and it may also help notifying the OP.

I got the fingerprint reader on my Dell XPS 13 9300 working in Ubuntu 20.04 with a [driver package](http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/pool/public/libf/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/) ostensibly from Dell. What I did was:

- install the latest Linux kernel 5.8 (most likely not necessary, but above 5.6.1 is advisable)
- download the .deb
- install it with `sudo dpkg -i libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.4-0ubuntu1somerville1_amd64.deb`
- reboot the system

This was the device installed in my XPS. Looks like it has the same ID as yours so you may be in luck.

```
 lsusb | grep -i goodix
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:533c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
```

Use is limited to logging in and probably some third-party software. Haven't yet found out if it can be used to get elevated permissions (in the GUI; I don't expect it ever to happen in the terminal).

**UPDATE**: I'm not quite sure what I did (it may have something to do with the `sudo pam-auth-update` I ran to enable fingerprint authentication), but this morning my laptop started asking for my fingerprint in the terminal when performing sudo commands. It doesn't *always* work for unlocking the computer or logging in, though, but it's better than nothing!

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been hoping to get the fingerprint working. Question tho; I read a lot of disparaging articles on updating beyond the 20.04LTS kernel 4.5, especially because of secure boot incompatibility. Can you confirm this isn't an issue on the 9300?

Comment: I can confirm the fingerprint reader works (although it's not as reliable as under Windows) with Kernel 5.6 which is generally advised for this notebook. Kernel 5.6 works flawlessly. 5.8 was a bit more problematic

Comment: Thanks! Your answer here helped another person who helped others in turn via the /r/Dell subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/ixwgm0/xps_15_9500_ubuntu_popos_fingerprint_howto/

Answer (score 0):

A firmware update for the fingerprint reader and, most likely, accompanying drivers are [promised](https://bartongeorge.io/2020/01/01/introducing-the-2020-xps-13-developer-edition-this-one-goes-to-32/) by Dell for mid-2020. I'd hold off a little longer.

Comment: Thank you. I read that they may not bother with the reader as in linux you need to identify many times whilst using terminal for example. I suppose sudo command may recognise the fingerprint in which case it would be a boon. If not, then less so.

Comment: it works with sudo yes, but in reality the fingerprint times out often and even if it works, it's nowhere near as accurate and fast as in Windows

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck. A Goodix employee has pushed out a driver for certain models, and I see your 533c is on the list (my 5385 is not :( )

[https://git.launchpad.net/~oem-solutions-engineers/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/+git/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eoem-solutions-engineers/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/+git/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/)

It looks like the guys gitlab page has been taken down, so not sure what this means for his ongoing employment :o

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.6 of the libfprint-2-tod1-goodix driver works for some fingerprint readers, including mine on Dell Inspiron 5482. That is with the 20.04 package version of fprintd. This broke on update to 22.04 - the driver makes fprintd in my case.

For 22.04 a new version seems to be needed, unless it is a fprintd bug.
The mentioned gitlab repo by @Wayno is still up if this one is meant:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint

That repo is aiming for open source drivers, not closed source goodix ones.
Everyone is highly recommended to check it out and help where possible.